# Finding a Word in a Binary Search Tree Java?

Tags: java, string, search, tree, binary-search-tree

The problem I'm having is that I have a binary search three, and all of the nodes contain string values rather than integer ones. It gets these strings from a txt file and places the individual lines of text from the file as nodes into the tree. There is no problem with this.

My problem is that I need a method that iterates through my tree and finds a specific word. I already have separate classes, BinarySearchTree and BinaryTreeNode to serve as the basis for the tree I'm trying to make. The words it needs to find are located in a file called "lookup test file copy.txt" and it needs to write the words that it finds to another file called "SearchResults.txt"

I just have no idea how to do it, so I'm looking for advice.

This is the method I need help with:

```
public boolean SearchWord(String target){
    //returns true if the target string exists in the dictionary
    // otherwise it returns false
    //ALSO you need to write the results of Search 
    //in an output file called "SearchResults.txt" 

    return false;
}
```

Here is all of my code, excluding the two other classes mentioned above, if it helps.

```
public class Dictionary {
    public BinaryTreeNode theBinaryTree; 
    /**
     * I need to read one string by one string
     * and then insert it into a tree. 
     * I need to read all of the strings in the source file, line by line, 
     * and insert them into my dictionary. 
     * After readinga  single string, it needs to put it into a tree. 
     * I first need to create the dictionary tree, 
     * and then implement these methods on the tree. 
     * The Dictionary type is string. 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */

    private BinaryTreeNode dictionaryTree;   // this is the tree within your dictionary class

       public Dictionary(String filePath) throws IOException{
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Dictionary.txt"));
             this.dictionaryTree = readFile(br);
             br.close();
       }


       public BinaryTreeNode readFile(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException{
             String word = reader.readLine();         
             if(word!=null){
                 return new BinaryTreeNode(word, readFile(reader), readFile(reader));            
             }else{
                 return new BinaryTreeNode() ;  // empty node or null?
             }      
         }


    /**
     * @return
     * Once again, I already have this method written and modified
     * within the BinarySearchTree class. 
     * I'm simply going to call it over here. 
     */
    public int CountWords(){
        //returns the number of words in the dictionary
        //This is just counting nodes. 

        BinarySearchTree Aria = new BinarySearchTree();
        return Aria.countNodes(dictionaryTree);     
    }

    public boolean SearchWord(String target){
        //returns true if the target string exists in the dictionary
        // otherwise it returns false
        //ALSO you need to write the results of Search 
        //in an output file called "SearchResults.txt" 

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * I already modified the print order method
     * in BinarySearchTree
     * to work with strings. 
     * So I just called it here on the dictionaryTree. 
     * @PrintOrderedDict()
     * 
     * However, I also had to modify the method, 
     * so that it wrote whatever values the method recieved
     * to teh output file. 
     */

    public void PrintOrderedDict() throws IOException{
        //Print the dictionary words 
        //in order in a new file called "OrderedDictionary.txt". 
        //Just modify print order to work with strings. 
        try {
        BinarySearchTree jojo = new BinarySearchTree();
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("OrderedDictionary.txt");

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        out.write(jojo.inorderPrint(dictionaryTree));

        out.close();}
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }

    }

    public boolean DeleteWord(String target){
        //delete the target word if it exits in the dictionary and return true
        //otherwise return false
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

----EDIT----

This is also a small sample of the "dictionary.txt" file (It's too long to put the entire thing in)

```
ourselves
out
over
own
same
shan't
she 
all
```

This is the "lookup test file copy.txt" file:

```
the
program
a
ours
house
ME
ours
main
java
whom
with
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, its a simple case of "if the word you're searching for is alphabetically lower than the one the cursor's on then move to the left, else move to the right." Do this recursively until you find the word and return true or you don't find the word at all and return false.

Comment: Try doing with pencil and paper, to see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included the most relevant code, which is BinaryTreeNode, so the field names used here are guesswork, however this will do it:

Method in Dictionary:

```
public boolean SearchWord(String target){
    boolean found = theBinaryTree.contains(word);
    // write the values of "target" and "found" to file (code omitted)
    return found;
}
```

Method in BinaryTreeNode:

```
private String word;
private BinaryTreeNode left;
private BinaryTreeNode right;

public boolean contains(String target) {
    if (target.equals(word))
        return true;
    BinaryTreeNode next = target.compareTo(word) < 0 ? left : right;
    return next != null && next.contains(target);
}
```

Comment: +1 but I'm hoping the OP will understand the use of ternary operator :)

Comment: This is very helpful, but I keep on getting error messages for the use of "word" in the Dictionary method.

Comment: @MariaStewart Did you read the part where Bohemian said "field names used here are guesswork"?

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a homework, so I will not steal the possibility of resolving it from you, but I will give you hints which you can use to easily solve your problem:

1. You already know the algorithm, if I understood correctly, so you know what you have to do with numbers. You need to do the same with Strings, just you don't know how to compare Strings.
2. Use the `compareTo` method. `s1.compareTo(s2)` is:

   - positive, if s1 > s2
   - negative, if s1 < s2
   - 0, if s1.equals(s2)
3. Comparable is an interface. If a class implements Comparable, it will have a compareTo method. String happens to implement Comparable, as you can see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem into parts.

1)  Do a search on how to read a file.  Read the file, and echo the results to standard output.  That is pretty easy, and about 1/3 of the work you need to do.

2)  Write some random words to a file.  Open the file, write the words, then check your work, also not hard to do and you are getting closer.

3)  Load your binary search tree and write code to do a look up, it is pretty easy.  If your word .equals the current node, return true  Otherwise if less than the current node, go left, if greater go right.  If your pointer is null, then return false;

4)  Put it all together.

Conquering this in parts is much less overwhelming.